# Is there a better way of checking multiple variables are a single type in Python?

Tags: python, exception, types, comparison

```
    if not [True]*3 == [isinstance(i, int) for i in [days, months, years]]:
        raise TypeError('days, months, and years must be int type not %s %s %s'
                        % (type(days), type(months), type(years)))
```

Basically want to check if days, months, and years is an int, the most compact way I could thing of is above but I'm not sure it's the best but I believe it would be better than multiple if statements for each int.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in [days, months, years]):
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in [days, months, years])
```